# Cannot click the <svg></svg> and input the value

Tags: python, css, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Cannot click the `<svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">...</svg>` and input the `<input class="opacity-0 absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full" type="date" max="2023-11-27" value="2023-10-27">` value = "2023-10-27" and then click "Apply"

four steps i want to use selenium to automatic
1)click `<svg></svg>` 
2)input value
3)click "apply"
4)print page source

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Setup the WebDriver 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Open the page
driver.get("https://www.investing.com/equities/tencent-holdings-hk-historical-data")

# Wait for the SVG element and click it
svg_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='__next']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span/svg/g/path")))
svg_element.click()

# Find the date input, clear it, and set a new value
date_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='date']")))
date_input.clear()
date_input.send_keys("2020-01-01")

# Find and click the "Apply" button
apply_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Apply']")))
apply_button.click()

# print page_source
page_source = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
page_source = page_source.decode('utf-8')
print(page_source)

# Remember to close the driver
driver.quit()
```

and cannot get any result after run the code, please help on this, thanks !

Error Log:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-325ef3fa9d48> in <module>
     17 
     18 # Wait for the SVG element and click it
---> 19 svg_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
     20     EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='__next']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span/svg/g/path")))
     21 svg_element.click()

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: what kind of error are you getting ?

Comment: error are "TimeoutException: Message: " i cannot see any error message from log, so i post it, thanks !

Comment: youre waiting for svg to be clickable and its not. Probably its not in view to be clicked. Try to scroll to it and then click it. Or try using javascript clicks, they can click items that are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems

At first visit there is a dialog to confirm agreement on using cookies.
Probably you need something like this XPath to click:

```
By.XPATH, "//*[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"
```

Your xpath will not work because the svg is in different namespace. Use this one instead:

```
By.XPATH, "//*[@id='__next']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span/*[local-name()='svg']/*[local-name()='g']/*[local-name()='path']"
```